# Access to the actual/visual DOM using custom elements and template

Tags: javascript, html, dom, custom-element

Say I have this thing called a "panel". It contains a hidden section and a button to show it. Easy enough.

However I got a little fancy and decided to use a custom element `<custom-panel>` to markup the boundaries for each panel, a `<template>` for the contents and `<slots>` for the configuration (title, details, etc).

Now I am a little confused as to how to hook up the buttons. The template has CSS that will show/hide the details of the panel if the correct class is set. But how to I set it? I have only figured out how to get to the contents of the template (without the resolved slots) or the custom-panel's contents (with no template information).

**Complete Example**:

```js
customElements.define(
  'custom-panel',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();

      const template = document.getElementById('custom-panel-template');
      const templateContent = template.content;

      this.attachShadow({
        mode: 'open'
      }).appendChild(
        templateContent.cloneNode(true)
      );
    }
  }
);
```

```html
  <custom-panel>
    <span slot="openButtonText">Open Panel 1</span>
    <span slot="closeButtonText">Close Panel 1</span>
    <span slot="panelName">Panel 1</span>
    <div slot="">Panel 1 Details</div>
  </custom-panel>
  <custom-panel>
    <span slot="openButtonText">Open Panel 2</span>
    <span slot="closeButtonText">Close Panel 2</span>
    <span slot="panelName">Panel 2</span>
    <div slot="panelContent">Panel 2 Details</div>
  </custom-panel>

  <template id="custom-panel-template">
        <style type="text/css">
            #panel {
                display: none;
            }
            
            #panel.open {
                display: revert;
            }
        </style>
        
        <!-- how do these get hooked in? -->
        <button type="button"><slot name="openButtonText">Default Open Button Text</slot></button>
        <button type="button"><slot name="closeButtonText">Default Close Button Text</slot></button>
        
        <fieldset id="panel">
            <legend><slot name="panelName">Default Panel Name</slot></legend>
            <slot name="panelContent">Default Panel Content</slot>
        </fieldset>
    </template>
```

Comment: You can write methods that use `this.classList` to add or remove classes from the element. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements#lifecycle_callbacks) for the callback methods you can define to perform actions at various stages in the lifecycle of the element.

Comment: Well so I guess I got a little side tracked when I was trying to figure it out. I was using innerHTML to see the contents and of course those values were misleading me. I didn't realize I could and should query the shadow root directly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
customElements.define(
  'custom-panel',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();

      const template = document.getElementById('custom-panel-template');
      const templateContent = template.content;

      this.attachShadow({
        mode: 'open'
      }).appendChild(
        templateContent.cloneNode(true)
      );

      // get a reference to the panel
      const panel = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#panel");

      // hookup the open
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector("button#open").addEventListener("click", () => {
        panel.className = "open";
      });


      // hookup the close
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector("button#close").addEventListener("click", () => {
        panel.className = "";
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its your own component, no one is ever going to set **multiple** Event Listeners to *one* button.
So use inline Event Handlers instead of `addEventListener`

You can then use cleaner DOM creation code with a `createElement( tag, props )` function

No need for a fancy `<template>` You only need to create a handful DOM elements.
If you did append a template use:
`this.shadowRoot.querySelector("button#open").onclick = (evt) => { }`

You also do not want to set a `[open]` **state** buried deep inside a *class* in shadowDOM.

State should be set on the Web Component itself as: `<custom-panel open>`

`:host(:not([open)) fieldset { display:none }` then toggles visibility

Also [read my Dev.To post](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/acme-the-accordion-web-component-in-187-bytes-47ah) on `<details-accordion>`

```html
<script>
customElements.define('custom-panel', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      const createElement = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
      super() // sets AND returns 'this'
        .attachShadow({mode:'open'}) // sets AND returns this.shadowRoot
        .append(
           createElement( 'style' , {
             innerHTML: `:host(:not([open])) fieldset { display:none }`   
           }),
           createElement( 'button', {
             innerHTML: `<slot name="openButtonText"></slot>`,
             onclick  : (evt) => this.open = true
           }),
           createElement( 'button', {
             innerHTML: `<slot name="closeButtonText"></slot>`,
             onclick  : (evt) => this.open = false
           }),
           createElement( 'fieldset', {
             // id : "panel" // not required
             innerHTML: `<legend><slot name="panelName">Default Panel Name</slot></legend>` +
                        `<slot name="panelContent">Default Panel Content</slot>`
           })
        );
    }
    get open(){
      return this.hasAttribute("open");
    }
    set open(state=true){
      this.toggleAttribute("open", state)
    }
    toggle(){
      this.open = !this.open;
    }
  });
</script>
<custom-panel>
  <span slot="openButtonText">Open Panel 1</span>
  <span slot="closeButtonText">Close Panel 1</span>
  <span slot="panelName">Panel 1</span>
  <div slot="">Panel 1 Details</div>
</custom-panel>
<custom-panel open>
  <span slot="openButtonText">Open Panel 2</span>
  <span slot="closeButtonText">Close Panel 2</span>
  <span slot="panelName">Panel 2</span>
  <div slot="panelContent">Panel 2 Details</div>
</custom-panel>
```